# How to tell when a mirrored disk is bad in Windows

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, backup, mirroring

When a disk is mirrored in windows you see it represented as one volume in windows explorer.  From my understanding, if one disk errors on read or write then windows will fall back to the other disk.  But how do you know when that happens? I wouldn't want to be unknowingly using a failed disk and then have the last disk in the mirror fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storage Spaces, it'll pop up a warning if a drive fails.

If you're just using mirroring through disk management. I've seen mixed results. Sometimes you'll get a popup, and sometimes you would need to check the event log to see if it is listed there.

I'd recommend using Storage spaces for mirroring.